# Create a list of Triangle objects

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm very new to Python and have an issue. I was wondering if there was a way I could create a list of objects created. For example, say I have a class:

```
list_triangles = []

def class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, h, w):
    self.h = h
    self.w = w

a = Triangle(5,6)
b = Triangle(3,3)
```

What I would have to add such that each time I defined a new object, it would append to `list_triangles`, such that in the end I have a list of objects?

e.g `list_triangles = (a, b)`

I'm thinking I'd have to make a for loop, but I'm not sure because what would I say `for i in range ____`?

Comment: `def class` should just be `class`

Answer (score 3):

Put the arguments in a list, then iterate over that.

```
params = [(5, 6), (3, 3)]
list_triangles = [Triangle(*p) for p in params]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have globaly accessible list of every created object, if so you can declare class variable and then append `self` to it in constructor to keep track of objects like so

```
class Cat():
    instances = []
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        Cat.instances.append(self)

a = Cat("Bob")
b = Cat("John")

print(Cat.instances)
print(Cat.instances[0].name)
```

Which results in

```
>> [<__main__.Cat object at 0x00000000014BE790>, <__main__.Cat object at 0x00000000014BE610>]
>> Bob
```